# Cast vote to close when owning a gold badge?

Tags: support, feature-request, dupehammer

Is it possible to just vote to close instead of authoritatively closing when in possession of a gold badge?

I'm not always 100% certain, and would much rather open a vote to see if other high-rep users agree with me rather than take the decision like a dictator.

Comment: You only wield the dup-hammer, Mjölnir, when closing a question as a duplicate. If unsure, leave a comment stating that it *might* be a duplicate rather than authoritatively closing the question.